# How to get the image name in process page in php

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have two file type input fields and the HTML code is below.

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="file" name="doc[anyname1]"  class="fileupload">
<input type="file" name="doc[anyname2]"  class="fileupload">        
<button  name="publishnow" class="btn themeBg">save now</button></form>
```

**Process.php**

I am checking like this  `print_r($_FILES['doc[anyname1]']['name']);`.

but I am getting the below error.

> Notice: Undefined index: doc[anyname1]

Can we use like this `$_FILES['doc[anyname1]']['name']`?

Comment: Just do print_r or var_dump of the complete $_FILES array, then you will see what the structure actually is …

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r($_FILES['doc['anyname1]]['name']);
```

This is a typo error. Check the name you gave your input tags and the $_FILES

Comment: I am getting the same error. that was the typo mistake.

Comment: print_r($_FILES['doc['anyname1']']['name']); Try this one again

Comment: Getting syntax error, unexpected 'anyname1' (T_STRING), expecting ']'